# Can't make phone call with Twilio : "No International Authorization"

Tags: twilio, telephony, phone-call

I bought some Twilio phone numbers.

To try them out I pointed them to a Twilio bin with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Dial>+33xxxxxxxxx</Dial>
</Response>
```

I tried calling different Swiss mobile phone numbers from the Swiss Twilio number but it fails with all of them with:

```
Warning - 13227

Dial: No International Authorization

Your account is not authorized to make international calls
```

I did the same trying to call French numbers with a French Twilio number but same result.

I am the owner of the account and I am not using a free account (I have credits on it). I can't find any option to enable international calls.

Comment: Have you gone in to https://www.twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions and enabled the countries you require?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

International countries need to be enabled in your Twilio account.
Go to this page to select the countries you need: http://twilio.com/console/voice/settings/geo-permissions

The same is true for SMS messages under their settings page: https://www.twilio.com/console/sms/settings/geo-permissions